# Sound issue on my Lenevo Yoga Creator 7 on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard, indicator-sound

I recently dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu 20.10, but what I found was muted sound device. When I tried changing the volume label, what I hear is irritating buzz sound, which does not seem to be fixed. I tried all the tweaks from the community but does not seem to work, so I reinstalled Ubuntu from USB, and this does not seem to be installation bug. Here are the sound devices:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Can someone guide me through this bug? I tried checking all alsa stuffs but does not seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean with this? all alsa stuffs

Comment: I meant alsamixer

Comment: It seems to be fixed now temporarily but I don't have the complete solution. sudo alsa force-reload followed by a system restart works for the time unless I restart my computer.  I have to rerun the same command everytime to get my sound back. Does anyone have permanent solution?